# Can't set background-image property to none

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen).

Each selected has a close button as seen in the snippet below. I want to change the color of the close button but after looking through its CSS property I have found out that it cannot be done since the plugin uses a `background-image` property.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, it has a property `background-image: 'chosen-sprite@2x.png';`.

Now I want to customize the `background-image` property of this using CSS but it doesn't work.

I have tried `background-image: none !important;`, `background-image: url('https://img.icons8.com/search') !important;`, and `background: none !important;` but no luck.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chosen-select').chosen({
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```css
a.search-choice-close {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">
  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="United States" selected>United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom" selected>United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
  </select>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: as you can see, it's working fine here

Comment: @TemaniAfif So I have tried it in both Firefox and Safari and it works but I'm using Chrome and it doesn't work.

Comment: I am using chrome and it works for me ... did you clear your cache?

Comment: try:     background: none !important;

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried clearing my cache, restarted my browser and still, the close button appears. I have tried to use another machine with the same Chrome version and it works.

Comment: are you on classic chrome or google canary? Because canary is still in development and in my experience weird things can happen sometimes with canary!

Comment: @Moose I'm using a classic Chrome.

Comment: This is so weird I'm using Chrome 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit), tried other machines with the same exact version of Chrome running OSX 10.13.4. I guess this can considered as solved since it does work on other instances of Chrome and works also in Safari and Firefox. Tried clearing cache, restarted browser, used incognito, and restarted machine.

Comment: very odd indeed. Perhaps reinstall chrome? Or did you try refreshing the page with Ctrl + F5?

Comment: After several days, I have found out the cause. jQuery Chosen uses media queries detecting the DPI of the screen. Since my MacBook has a retina display it uses the media query CSS instead. As a fix, you also need to override the CSS inside the media query.

Comment: @downvoter Check the answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the code below:

```
a.search-choice-close {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

I have found out that jQuery Chosen uses CSS media queries detecting the DPI of the screen.

So the fix is:

```
a.search-choice-close {
  background-image: none !important;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
    background-image: none !important;
  }
}
```

Overriding the basic CSS isn't enough in some cases.